# Drawer of DrawerLayout above DialogFragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-alertdialog

I have my application with a lateral menu using the DrawerLayout class.
Generally I'm happy with the design, but I need to be able to show a dialog blocking the "normal" interface, but with a button in the dialog that opens the Drawer (where I have a section with an input element). At this point I need to let the Dialog open, but "covered" with the Drawer.

I can bind the click and open the drawer, but, visually, it is below the dialog.

Is there a way I can put the Drawer "above" the Dialog?

what I have (orrible ascii-art)

```
+--------------+-------------------------------+
|drawer element|      rest of my activity      |
|line1         |          (in background)      |
|line2    +---------------------------+        |
|....     |dialog                     |        |
|         |                           |        |
|         +---------------------------+        |
|              |                               |
|              |                               |
+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

what I want (orrible ascii-art)

```
+--------------+-------------------------------+
|drawer element|      rest of my activity      |
|line1         |          (in background)      |
|line2         |----------------------+        |
|....          |g                     |        |
|              |                      |        |
|              |----------------------+        |
|              |                               |
|              |                               |
+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: unfortunately I need to show the read content below the dialog; it's not a full screen element (at least in landscape mode)

Comment: I hope the added ascii-art can convey what I want to achieve.